# Profiling partial programs in Linux

Tags: linux, profiler, gprof

I have a program in which significant amount of time is spent loading and saving data. Now I want to know how much time each function is taking in terms of percentage of the total running time. However, I want to exclude the time taken by loading and saving functions from the total time considered by the profiler. Is there any way to do so using gprof or any other popular profiler?

Comment: That's what `gprof` is actually good at (provided you have no recursion), because it doesn't sample during I/O.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Similarly you can use

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind --collect-atstart=no --toggle-collect=<function>
```

Other options to look at:

```
--instr-atstart    # to avoid runtime overhead while not profiling
```

To get instructionlevel stats:

```
--collect-jumps=yes
--dump-instr=yes
```

*Alternatively you can 'remote control' it on the fly: **`callgrind_control`** or annotate your source code (IIRC also with branch predictions stats): **`callgrind_annotate`**.*

The excellent tool `kcachegrind` is a **marvellous** visualization/navigation tool. I can hardly recommend it enough:

[image]

Comment: +1 Would give more if I could. `valgrind` and `kcachegrind` are an amazing pair!

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I'm in a hurry at the moment. Don't want to learn new profilers at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

I would consider using something more modern than `gprof`, such as `OProfile`. When generating a report using `opreport` you can use the `--exclude-symbols` option to exclude functions you are not interested in.

See the [OProfile webpage](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net) for more details; however for a quick start guide see the [OProfile docs](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/docs/) page.

Comment: But OProfile is a system wide profiler. I don't think it gives very accurate results for individual process profiling.

Comment: Yes, OProfile has the ability to do system-wide profiling; but you can filter it to give data for a single application binary or process (it can tag all data it collects with the process it came from).

Comment: It's pretty accurate in my experience.

Comment: I'm in a hurry at the moment so it would be good if some simple solution in gprof exists.

Answer (score 2):

[Zoom](http://rotateright.com) from RotateRight offers a system-wide time profile for Linux. If your code spends a lot of time in i/o, then that time won't show up in a time profile of the CPUs. Alternatively, if you want to account for time spent in i/o, try the "thread time profile".

Answer (score 0):

for a simple, basic solution, you might want log data to a csv file.

e.g. Format [functionKey,timeStamp\n]

... then load that up in Excel.  Get the deltas, and then include or exclude based on if functions.  Nothing fancy.  On the upside, you could get some visualisations fairly cheaply.